# How to call function in another function in extjs4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am working in extjs4. How do I call member function (hellotest) within another member function (showSubject)?

I am trying to add a call to `hellotest` in the `tabchange` event of `subjectBar` (which is part of the `showSubject` function). I tried to use scope the function call using this, but this didn't work and I got the following error: `object[object object] error undefined function`

Here is my some code:

```
Ext.define('Am.DnycontentcategoriesController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function () {

        this.control({
            //'viewport > panel >Contentcategories':
            'Contentcategories': {
                render: this.showSubject,
            }
        });
    },
    hellotest: function () {
        console.log("inside hello test function");
    },


    showSubject: function () {
        //console.log(this.hellotest());
        subjectBar.on('tabchange', function () {
            //here I am getting error 
            this.hellotest();
            var tab = subjectBar.getActiveTab();
            --------

        });
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the `scope` to `this`:

```
showSubject: function () {
    subjectBar.on('tabchange', function () {
        this.hellotest();
        var tab = subjectBar.getActiveTab();
    }, this);
}
```

> The scope (this reference) in which the handler function is executed. Defaults to the `Element`

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.EventManager-method-on